# libgazebo_player not working

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to make Gazebo work with player and was going trying to go through the examples but every time I try open player I get the following error. Player has been working fine for me with stage so far. I am only having problems with Gazebo.

error   : Failed to load plugin libgazebo_player.
error   : libtool reports error: file not found
error   : plugin search path: /home/fahad/Spider:.:/usr/local/lib64/
error   : failed to load plugin: libgazebo_player
error   : failed to parse config file camera.cfg driver blocks

Gazebo does detect that player is installed.
Any one else has encountered the same problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/467/libgazebo_player-not-working/) by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 39 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The binary gazebo .deb was built without Player support, so it doesn't have the player plugin library.  It seems like a good idea to start building Player support into the .deb.  I created a [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo-release/issue/14/gazebo-debs-should-include-player-support) for that.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1